# GQL Query Limit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a NDB Model

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
   accId = ndb.StringProperty()
   firstName = ndb.StringProperty()
   lastName = ndb.StringProperty()
```

So now I need to query on this model and get account Id's of all people having firstName as Mark. So I wrote the query...

```
acc_obj = Account.gql("WHERE firstName = :1","Mark")
```

But using the above query whenever I print count it limits to 1000 only.

```
print acc_obj.count()
```

I know that the count is more than 1000 but somehow the gql query fetches on 1000 entities at one time.

- So why there is this limitation (explanation)?
- And what is the other alternative to fetch all other records at once without using limit,cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there used to be a hard limit that got lifted:

[Google App Engine - getting count of records that match criteria over 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799339/google-app-engine-getting-count-of-records-that-match-criteria-over-1000?rq=1)

But maybe it only got lifted for certain mechanisms and not others.

For example in the remote api-shell, the 1000 limit still exists

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35893498

If you are able to recreate your query in NDB, you won't experience the limit:

[google app engine NDB records counts from NDB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946950/google-app-engine-ndb-records-counts-from-ndb-model/52956324#52956324)